# 301 редирект с Главной страницы на языковую версию

Tags: редирект, http-status-code-301

Подскажите пожалуйста Ваше мнение по поводу редиректов, которые идут с Главной страницы сразу на укр.версию сайта, т.е редирет настроен так: https://site   идет  301 на: https://site/uk/

Считаю что это ошибка - но руководить и программист меня не слышат, не знаю как еще им обосновать тот факт, что нужно снять 301 редирект. Может подскажите статьи какие-то или поясните почему нужно снять редирект.

Еще момент через оператор site: показывается 2 домена, они правда все компании, но подскажите как так вышло, что все системы парсинга также видят отдельный сайт, внутренних ссылок со вторым доменом на основном сайте нет нигде. Скажите это бок программиста, который на уровне сервера подвязал 2 сайта к одному и какие действия?

Comment: А почему, по-вашему, нужно убрать редирект и в чём ошибка?

Comment: Спасибо, не говорю что это прямо ошибка, но переживаю по поводу индексации и поведенческих факторов). Как по мне Главная страница с 200 ответом куда лучше чем 301 редирект, возможно и ошибаюсь, но главная страница сразу идет на укр.версию, а ру версия имеет префикс ру, т.е домен не отдает ответ 200